# How can I utilize two default scoped objects in a test without making it public?

Tags: java, unit-testing, scope

Consider two classes that sit in two packages:

```
package com.foobar.barers;

abstract class BaseFooBarer<T> extends BaseBarer{ ... }
```

and

```
package com.foobar.unbarers;

abstract class BaseFooUnbarer<T> extends BaseUnbarer{ ... }
```

Now anything thing that can be "barred" by a BaseBarer should be able to be "unbarred" by a BaseUnbarer. But a BaseFooBarer also contains the method "BarredFoo getBarredFoo()" and "void setFoo(Foo foo)". A BaseFooUnbarer contains the method "Foo getFoo()" and "void setBarredFoo(BarredFoo barredFoo)". Given that I have several implementations of BaseFooBarer and their corresponding BaseFooUnbarer, I thought it would be easiest to test it using a parameterized junit test. Unfortunately, since they sit in separate packages I can't place the test in a package that can access both. So I'm left with either making five nearly identical tests starring the public implementations or making these things public.

Now I have no desire in making them public because I don't want anybody extending them other than the implementations in my jar. I also don't want five redundant tests in my code.

Is there any pattern in Java that will allow me to have my cake and eat it too?

There's a limitation in which I'm unable to move these classes into one package, so I can't take the easy way out.

Comment: If the implementations are in different packages, how can they extend this package-private base class?

Comment: No. The implementations are in the same packages as their base. The "barer" and "unbarer" are in different packages. The implementations of "BaseFooBarer" and "BaseFooUnbarer" are public.

Comment: plz clean up the question. you write some code and then you add that there are some additional methods. be more explicit because it's hard to understand how your hierarchy exactly looks like and what methods are there